# Servlet get date and time

Tags: java, datetime, servlets, time, sqldatetime

I'm using the following code to get the date and time

```
public class offer extends HttpServlet {


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet offer</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1> sv sugar mills</h1>");
        doPost(request,response);
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
} 

 @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
     response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     java.sql.Date sqlDate=null,ofrmonth=null,ctime=null;

    dat="14/02/2013";
    try
    {
     java.util.Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dat);
     //ctime=new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
     sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
     out.println(sqlDate);
     out.Println(ctime);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     out.println(e);
    }
 }
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>

}
```

Here, the util.Date variable date is displayed as "Thu Feb 14 00:00:00 IST 2013". So I get the sql.Date easily as "2013-02-14". Also, I want to get the time from it. In the ctime variable I want to get the time and display it. The format should be 24hours format. But I don't know how to get it.

I've used some functions like getHours() and getDate(), but I couldn't found the solution. Can someone help me to get the time. Thanks in advance

I need the time as 00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss)

Comment: Please post compilable code that actually demonstrates what problem you're having. As-is your question makes little sense; you don't *have* a time, only a date. Furthermore `java.sql.Date` is *only* the date - it represents a SQL DATE

Comment: Please consult the documentation for [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), and [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).  There is a ton of information in these links.  You should also google around for some simple examples.  Unless you have a specific need, you should use `java.util.Date` rather than `java.sql.Date`, which you are currently using.

Comment: What `doPost` is being used for here is nonsensical.  Instead of using `doPost` for this you should make another function called something like `printDate()` and call that in your `doGet`.  `doPost` should never call `doGet` nor should `doGet` call `doPost` unless that is all they are doing, namely to make both do the exact same thing. And even that, most developers would frown on. But at least that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sqlDate);
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.HOUR));
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Unless you set a time zone for the `Calendar` object the above returns time in your machine's time zone.

And if you want a single `String` in the form of `HH:mm:ss` as output, you can use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) as pointed out by @zvzdhk.

Snippet:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(sqlDate));
```

Note that `TimeZone.getTimeZone` allows argument like `"GMT+5:30"`, `"PST"` etc. Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29) for more.